# Cannot connect to database SQLdeveloper oracle xe version

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-xe

I tried many ways to connect to the database but it all failed. I used to be able to connect to the database through selecting TNS then network alias XE. But after I installed SAS and connected to oracle through SAS this way failed. I don't know if there is a connection between these.
[image: TNS connect error]

I also tried to connect through Basic but it shows the error:
[image: Basic connect error]

When I changed from Basic to local it shows an error again
[local connect error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RZsw.png)

I tried the ways suggested on stack flow by going to preference-database-advanced [image: and sel]ected oracle home and set the directory to the tnsnames.ora file location. But this still didn't work. It shows the error "...\admin\jdba\lib is not a valid jar file". Ｉonly put the address till "...\admin" I don't know why did this error pop up.

Please help me solve this... I have struggled with this for a long time and I have a project using this to turn in within 2 days. I used to uninstall oracle and install again but the same errors were still there.

Comment: If XE database is on your machine, it's not running

Comment: Hi. Do you mean the oracle xe is not running? How can I run that on my computer? When I type oracle in windows it shows oracle instance manager then it shows the "oracleserviceXE" status "running" and then I tried to connect, it still didn't work.

Comment: There should be a listener process, listening on port 1521, there's not, hence your error. Lsnrctl status, from a cmd prompt

Comment: So how can I solve this error? I don't quite understand how to do that

Comment: Jeff said that you should open command prompt (CMD) (it is a Windows program). It lets you type commands. So, type (literally) `lsnrctl status` and press the ENTER key. Copy/paste the result back here (not as a comment - edit the original question you posted).

Comment: instead of teaching you how to install oracle from scratch and use it, it would be easier for you to use a pre-built VM like this - https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/databaseappdev-vm.html

Comment: Thanks for all the help! I solved this by open the "services.msc" then ran the oracle listener.